# Does rotating proxy provide better privacy?

Tags: privacy, proxy, tor

We have anonymous rotating proxy service like [ProxyMesh](http://proxymesh.com/).

> ProxyMesh provides 14 rotating IP address proxy servers, each with 10 IP addresses rotating twice per day, giving you a total of 280 IP addresses per day. When you make a request thru one of these 14 anonymous proxy servers, your request will be randomly routed through one of 10 different proxy IP servers. This make it much harder for sites to track you based on IP addresses. And each location changes IP addresses twice a day, to help you get around IP bans or avoid IP rate limits.

Actually you could build your own rotating proxy via Tor, like [this](https://github.com/mattes/rotating-proxy).

Obviously the website you visit could use other technology to track down you(like Cookies). My question is: does rotating proxy increase the difficulty to find your real IP?

Answer (score 3):

> does rotating proxy increase the difficulty to find your real IP?

**No**. Your "real IP" is either disclosed in some way, or it is not. If it is not, it does not matter how many proxies you pass through.

Multiple proxies may make more difficult to track your *activity*, i.e. establish that actions A and B were both performed by the same entity (for that, see *fingerprinting*, below).

It might be argued that the more proxies you use, the more likely that one of them will be compromised or misconfigured and will leak your address. In this case the likelihood is low because all proxies will probably be centrally managed.

On the other hand, by using cookies and fingerprinting (you may want to google "panopticlick"), it becomes possible to mark all of your connections as belonging to the same user, let's call him "UNKNOWN-1".

Now knowing that UNKNOWN-1 is using fourteen different servers, if they are distributed around the planet, it is possible, using timing techniques, to estimate the distance (both in hops and in kilometers) between UNKNOWN-1 and each of those servers, albeit with a possibly conspicuous error margin.

If the proxies don't employ time fudging techniques, and chances are that they don't, it becomes possible to restrict your location geographically. Your real IP is still unrevealed, but you're *less* anonymous than if you used a single proxy.

There are also much more complicated techniques that cross-check your timing data with real-time network traffic status ("Internet weather"). They require resources, time, and a lot of traffic from your host to some monitored facility (even a single website might do). For example if I have restricted your location to somewhere in Southern Europe, if your connections through the Amsterdam proxy begin lagging when the route from Amsterdam to GARR is hosed, and you stop lagging when service is restored, my confidence of you being in Italy increases greatly. At that point I start monitoring service levels for Italian providers...

Answer (score 0):

On the network layer it doesn't really matter how many proxies within a chain are or how many proxies in your rotation are: Your real IP address is cascaded and should not be revealed.

But as you mentioned there might be fingerprinting techniques (e.g. user-agent individualism, cookies) or other leakages (e.g. announcing source addresses in SMTP and HTTP headers).

But the proxy rotation might increase the effort to profile your activities regarding your proxy usage. If you can live with the impact regarding connection speed and reliability, you might want to enable this mode. Otherwise it is questionable in most cases as long as you're not a secret agent, dissident, terrorist, criminal or top politician.

Comment: The question is about finding your IP, not tracking activities